# How can I change folder "Last Documents" properties at Win-7?

Tags: windows-7

My W-7 is russian, and I don't know how it is called in english. To translate this folder name into english is "Last Documents". It is the system folder, and last looked or changed docs signs are there. But I can't see there *.pdf files, for example. And I don't want to see there some files as *.exe or *.dll after i see them in viewer.

I want to configure this folder as I want. Is it possible?

Comment: I believe the name in English is "Recent documents" or "Recent places."

Answer (score 0):

Understand that the folder is dynamically populated with files opened via any application (or some of them). It seems that the folder is called `Recent Items` in English Windows version. More information about this I found on [page](http://www.sysprobs.com/windows-7-documents-location) and [page](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-clear-or-delete-my-recent-documents-in-windows/). I would expect to see files like `*.doc` or `*.xls` etc. PDF viewer should have some ability to populate this folder.